# Error in Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the said error, help is appreciated thank you.

```
Dim GSTPrice As Double = Val(txtGst.Text / 100) * Val(txtSubTotal.Text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use it like this:

```
Dim GSTPrice As Double = Val(txtGst.Text)/100 * Val(txtSubTotal.Text)
```

as txtGst.Text is a string you can not divide it by 100.